# channels.fetchMessage not firing then in a raw event

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a Discord bot that will give a role based on the reaction. Currently, I am testing if the raw events will fire.

I'm not sure why, but channels.fetchMessage won't fire .then, and I have tried manually inputting the channel ID which still won't respond.

I am running on Discord.js ^12.1.1

This is not a full code sample as I have took out the client login at the very end

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", async () => {

    client.user.setActivity('Redacted');

});

client.on('raw', packet => {
    // We don't want this to run on unrelated packets
    if (!['MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD', 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE'].includes(packet.t)) return;


    // Grab the channel to check the message from
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get(packet.d.channel_id);

    // There's no need to emit if the message is cached, because the event will fire anyway for that
    //if (channel.messages.has(packet.d.message_id)) return;


    // Since we have confirmed the message is not cached, let's fetch it
    console.log("Passed")


    channel.fetchMessage(packet.d.message_id).then(message => {

        console.log("Passed Again")


        // Emojis can have identifiers of name:id format, so we have to account for that case as well
        const emoji = packet.d.emoji.id ? `${packet.d.emoji.name}:${packet.d.emoji.id}` : packet.d.emoji.name;


        // This gives us the reaction we need to emit the event properly, in top of the message object
        const reaction = message.reactions.get(emoji);


        // Adds the currently reacting user to the reaction's users collection.
        if (reaction) reaction.users.set(packet.d.user_id, client.users.get(packet.d.user_id));


        // Check which type of event it is before emitting
        if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_ADD') {
            console.log("yes")
        }


        if (packet.t === 'MESSAGE_REACTION_REMOVE') {
            console.log("no")
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not fetching the channel the right way, you need to fetch the GuildChannel.

Your solution would be:

```js
const channel = client.guilds.cache.get(guildID).channels.cache.get(channelID);

channel.messages.fetch(messageID);
```

Comment: Thank you but for some reason this results in addRole is not a function
let user = message.guild.members.cache.get(packet.d.user_id)
let role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(x => x.name === "Member");
user.addRole(role)

Comment: `addRole` is indeed not a function starting from discord.js v12 you need to use `roles.add` instead, here is the documentation for this: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add

Comment: Wow! A lot has changed with Discord.js since I had used it. Thank you for your help.